# Query # of emails a specific subscriber received in the last 30 days

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

Having trouble getting the SQL right for this. I'm looking to get a total count of emails a specific subscriber received in the last 30 days. But it keeps failing. I'd also like to be able to query what those emails were during that same timeframe.

```
SELECT s.SubscriberKey COUNT (SubscriberKey) AS SENT_COUNT FROM _Sent
WHERE JobID IN (SELECT JobID FROM _Job WHERE SubscriberKey = 'XXX')
and EventDate between '2022-07-18' and '2022-08-18'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "keeps failing"?

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT s.SubscriberKey, COUNT (s.SubscriberKey) AS SENT_COUNT 
    FROM _Sent s
    inner join _Job j on j.jobid = s.jobid
WHERE SubscriberKey = 'XXX'
  and s.EventDate > getdate()-30
group by s.SubscriberKey
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Props for this sargable criteria!  The `getDate()` returns a timestamp, so it'd be better to make sure you get the whole day of events with `and s.EventDate > convert(date, getDate()-30)`.